# 'No Such Table' SqliteDatabase

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gradle

I always get this error. My database is created by myself. I don't create it with code I mean.  It creates it from assets folder and if I open it via a Sqlite reader application from my phone it shows tables and data perfectly. However I cannot read this database in my project. It creates database but cannot read from application. My connection class is an .aar file, and I added it to gradle. This is my helper code:

```
public class Connection extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String _dbPath;
private static String _dbName;

private final Context _context;

public Connection(Context context, int dbVer, String dbPath, String dbName) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVer);
    this._context = context;
    _dbPath = dbPath;
    _dbName = dbName;

    CreateDatabase();
}

public void CreateDatabase() {
    boolean dbExist = CheckDatabase();

    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            CopyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error.");
        }
    }
}

private boolean CheckDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = _dbPath + "/" + _dbName;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void CopyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = _context.getAssets().open(_dbName);

    String outFileName = _dbPath + "/" + _dbName;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}}
```

And this is my access code:

```
public static Cursor Select(Context context, Select select, ArrayList<Where> whereList) {
    String dbPath, dbName;
    Integer dbVer;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    Cursor cursor;

    dbVer = (Integer) TDTools.ReturnResource(context, R.integer.dbVer, TDTools.ResType.Integer);
    dbName = (String) TDTools.ReturnResource(context, R.string.dbName, TDTools.ResType.String);
    dbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + (String) TDTools.ReturnResource(context, R.string.dbPath, TDTools.ResType.String);

    Connection con = new Connection(context, dbVer, dbPath, dbName);
    database = con.getReadableDatabase();

    WhereArgs whereArgs = WhereArgs.CreateArguments(whereList);

    if (select == null) {
        select = new Select();
    }

    //Here is where i get 'No Such Table' error...
    cursor = database.query("Category", select.getColumns(), whereArgs.getWhereClauses(), whereArgs.getArguments(), null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

**UPDATE** (Helper code)

```
public class Connection extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static SQLiteDatabase DataBase;

    private String _dbPath;
    private String _dbName;

    private final Context _context;

    public Connection(Context context, int dbVer, String dbPath, String dbName) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVer);
        this._context = context;
        this._dbPath = dbPath;
        this._dbName = dbName;

        CreateDatabase();
    }

    public void CreateDatabase() {
        boolean dbExist = CheckDatabase();

        if (!dbExist) {
            //this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                CopyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Veritabanı kopyalanamadı...");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean CheckDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = this._dbPath + "/" + this._dbName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            checkDB = null;
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void CopyDatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = this._context.getAssets().open(this._dbName);

        String outFileName = this._dbPath + "/" + this._dbName;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you deinstall the app on the device? Assets get only deployed once per install. If you change something to the DB file it will not be replaced automatically

Comment: i tried it now but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uppercase tablename "CATEGORY". If this doesn't work have a look if you are really opening your created database or just opened a new one.

You can examine the database for exxample with this command:

```
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;
```

---

**UPDATE**

General advice: add logmesseages to your code, so that you can understand what is happening.

Some thoughts about your code:

```
} catch (SQLiteException e) {
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
}
```

Probably you want to set chechDB = null here, because to database cannot be opened and is corrupted (needs to be recopied).

```
if (!dbExist) {
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        CopyDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error.");
    }
}
```

Why are you calling `this.getReadableDatabase()` before you copy the database?

---

**UPDATE 2**

You call `super(context, dbName, null, dbVer);` which means the database-file "dbName" is opened. But you copy the database to `this._dbPath + "/" + this._dbName`! You have to use the same path.

```
super(context, dbPath + "/" + dbName, null, dbVer);
```

Comment: SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name; this code returns just one table named meta_data

Comment: i changed my helper code like you wrote in my first message but it did not change anything. I check my database before setting cursor and it's open.

Comment: when i changed my access code like database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); instead of database = con.getReadableDatabase(); i get an error like unknown error (code 10): Could not open database

Comment: this is it man. thanks. update 2 works perfectly. thanks again. brilliant answer.